# Multiple schedules in Azure Devops Release Pipeline for different branches

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a Release pipeline with three environments. I have a single build pipeline (`_TestCM`) that builds different branches (`develop`, `Master`, `release`). All branch builds are CI builds.

[image: Release pipeline]

I applied an artifact filter to each environment.

[image: Artifact filter]

I want to deploy

```
Develop branch --> Environment 1 at 11:30 AM, 3 PM daily
Master branch --> Environment 2 at 5 AM, 7 PM daily
Release branch --> Environment 3 at 6 AM, 2 PM daily.
```

How can I configure the above scheduling requirement in a single release pipeline? Creating multiple release pipelines with single environment in each pipeline is not an option as we have hundreds of release pipelines.  Release pipeline need to trigger at the scheduled time only if there are any changes from that branch.

If it is not possible in a single Release pipeline, what are the options we have for accomplishing this task considering the hundreds of Release pipelines?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, I am afraid that it is not possible in a single release pipeline.

> Release pipeline need to trigger at scheduled time only if there any changes from that branch.

For this requirement, there is an Option in Release Pipeline(
**Only schedule releases if the source or pipeline has changed**).

[image]

According to your deploy process, you need to determine the environment via the branches. So you need to add multiple artifacts for multiple branches.

In this case, this option will not meet your needs. It treats all atifacts as a whole. When one of the branches changes, the release will be triggered by the schedule and all artifacts of different branches will be deployed at the same time.

You can achieve your needs by creating multiple pipelines.

The following are the settings you can refer to：

When you add artifacts, you can select the branch and enable the option:Only schedule releases if the source or pipeline has changed.

For example:

[image]

In environemnt, you can directly set schedule trigger without other settings.

[image]

You need to create the corresponding number of release pipelines according to your branches.

Comment: Thanks Kevin.  Considering the volume of Release pipelines(100+) with above requirement is it possible to accomplish the schedule using Rest Api in a separate pipeline that takes Release Definitions names as input ?

Comment: Yes. You can use this Rest API:  [Release Definition update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

Comment: If possible, can you provide a sample script using Powershell that takes Release definition names as input and have my schedule requirement accomplished with a single pipeline. When the release is triggered deployment should happen only if there any changes from that branch.